# Firebase retrieve Data from child by key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: I have my database structure like below in the snapshot]

Now what I am trying to do is to get all the children having `category` value of `shop`

I have tried this code

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://top-africa.firebaseio.com/businesses/);
ref.orderByChild("category").equalTo("shop");
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  String s) {
                Object ob = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + " blog posts==" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }
 });
```

but when I look at the log it printed out all 10 children whereas I suppose I would retrieve only one because there was only one value for `category` `shop`.

I don't know what I am missing. Could you please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your reference is pointing to bussiness, so use query to fetch the data with condition

```
Query mQuery = ref.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Shop");
mQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot,  String s) {
                Object ob = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + " blog posts==" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }
 });
```

Comment: Where exactly is your code other than OP's code? And please always add some explanation to code, otherwise it can't be a good answer.

Comment: I gave only summarised info .I just changed the code you mentioned but now i am not getting any value.